# What is the difference between "the one thing" and "only thing"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Do "the one thing" and "only thing" mean the same?

Consider the following:

1. Basketball is the one thing that X is can do and Y cannot.
2. Basketball is the only thing that X is can do and Y cannot.

Are there any differences between these?

Comment: In this context, they mean the same.  (Your sentences should read "that X can do", by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 means the only / the single difference between X and Y is in their ability to play basketball.

Number 1 has a similar meaning, but it doesn't necessarily imply that the ability to play basketball is the only difference between X and Y. It's only one of the differences and to the speaker, it's the most important difference between the two.

In other words, number 1 means, there is one thing that X can do, but Y cannot, and I think that thing is the most important thing, or the only difference between the two I know of, but it's not necessarily the only difference.

Comment: As a native speaker, I disagree. _The one thing, the only thing_ and _the one and only thing_ all mean the same to me. _One thing_ (without the definite article)  would be used for one of several.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks Kate. I read the opinions of other native speakers on other forums to come up with that explanation. The question has been asked before on other websites such as wordreference.